# Getting empty $roles array in CheckRole middleware

Tags: php, laravel

**I am facing issue  to check user roles in middleware getting empty $roles array**

User.php Model

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password','role_id',
];

 public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
    }
```

CheckRole.php      Middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$roles)
{       
echo "<pre>"; print_r($roles); die();

       if($request->user()->hasRole($roles) || !$roles)
        {
            return $next($request);
        }

        abort(404);
    }
```

web.php

```
 Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'roles'], 'roles:admin'], function () {
    //echo "admin"; die();
    Route::get('/abc', function () {
       echo"sds";
    });

    });
```

> https://gist.github.com/amochohan/8cb599ee5dc0af5f4246

Role.php  Roles Model

```
 protected $table =['roles'];

protected $fillable =['title'];
```

Comment: Did you added `'roles' => \App\Http\Middleware\YOUR_MIDDLEWARE_CLASS_NAME::class,` to `$routeMiddleware` property inside `kernel.php` file ?

Comment: yes i have added  in the  $routeMiddleware

Comment: Does your user has only 1 role ?

Comment: no user has multiple roles

Comment: So if your user has multiple roles you must use  

`public function roles() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Role');
 }`

Comment: thanks brother  but this is not working , i think hasOne method   has a Problem in Laravel

Comment: Could you plz add your User, Role models and your db schema ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
//...
Route::middleware('auth', 'roles:admin')->group(function () {

    // This route is protected by auth & admin middlewares
    Route::get('/abc', function () {
       dump('abc');
    });

});
```

CheckRole middleware

```
class CheckRole
{
    /**
     * Handle the incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string  $role
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
    {
        if (! $request->user()->hasRole($role)) {
            // Redirect...
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Comment: I want to check role in web.php

Answer (score 0):

In `CheckRole.php` middleware you are calling a method `$request->user()->hasRole($roles)`, which is you don't have `hasRole()` function inside your User model and no argument passed tho.
You can try my approach here if only have 1 role

**User.php**

```
public function hasRole()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Role','id','role_id');
}
```

And in your custom middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::user()->hasRole->role_name == "whatever role you want")
    {
        return $next($request);
    }
    //redirect to everywhere you want
}
```

If your user have multiple role, try this
**User.php**

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Role','id','role_id');
}

public function hasRole(string $role)
{
    $roles = $this->roles();
    foreach($roles as $permission)
    {
        if($permission->role_name == $role)
        {
          return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

In your middleware just do this

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::user()->hasRole("whatever role"))
    {
        return $next($request);
    }
    //redirect to everywhere you want
}
```

Comment: Oh ya i forget, in the $permission just get the attribute in your database $permission->role_name; i edited my answer.